# $p$-modular splitting systems and the characteristic of the ring $\mathcal{O}$

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, modular-representation-theory

Let $k=\overline{k}$ be a field of characteristic $p$.
Let $(K,\mathcal{O},k)$ be a $p$-modular system.
Let both $k$ and $K$ be splitting fields for $G$ and its subgroups.

The ring $\mathcal{O}$ can have characteristic zero or characteristic $p$.

> What is the difference? Which are important implications that follow in the first case but not in the latter one (and vice versa)?

I would be grateful for a book or another reference. Thank you.

Comment: Related question on M.SE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4757141/can-both-fields-in-a-p-modular-system-be-algebraically-closed-at-the-same-time

Comment: It's much more usual to assume that $K$ has characteristic zero. This is what leads to the usual theory of decomposition numbers and so on. See for example Feit's book, "The Representation Theory of Finite Groups".